# Is there a way to permanently add an item to a list file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a Python script that should let me add a list of guilds and sort them alphabetically. Since I've already had a list of guilds, I've written a Python file that contains a list of the names I already had. Now I need to append the new items to that list, since the program is supposed to be used multiple times, and I need the complete list to be saved with the new items I input after each use.

This is my current code:

```py
from g_list import guilds  # imports the guilds list from the g_list.py folder


def g_add():
    f = open('Guilds_Sorted.txt','w')
    f.write("\n".join(guilds))
    f.close()
    while True:
        guild = input("What is the guild's name ? ") # can this input be saved back in the guilds list in g_list.py
        f = open('Guilds_Sorted.txt', "a")
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(guild)
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Do you know how to write a file? As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: May I ask why you have your list of guilds in a .py anyway? I think what you're trying to do is something you'd normally accomplish with files anyway - that is, storing data between runs. Whats wrong with storing your guilds in a file and reading from the file when you run the script?

Comment: user10987432 i do not mind at all i didn't know any better that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible to update a Python file which you will later import, it is extremely uncommon.

Why don't you store your initial guilds in the text file, and then add new guilds to it using the Python script? That can be done like this:

```py
PATH = 'Guilds_Sorted.txt'


def main():
    # First read the already saved guilds from the file into memory:
    with open(PATH, 'rt') as file:
        guilds = file.read().splitlines()

    # Now ask the user to add new guilds:
    while True:
        guild = input("What is the guild's name ? ")
        if not guild:
            break
        guilds.append(guild)

    # If you want, you can sort the list here, remove duplicates, etc.
    # ...

    # Write the new, complete list back to file:
    with open(PATH, 'wt') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(guilds))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that I added an exit condition. By entering no name (empty string), the program quits.

Comment: Thank you, any documentaition // tutorials i can read to get familiarized with this ?

Comment: @Koriyou, you're welcome. The [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/) is extremely useful, although I can imagine it's a bit overwhelming in the beginning. You might start with the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), and browse a bit through the site now and then. Long ago, I started with [A Byte of Python](https://python.swaroopch.com/), which may be a bit more "user friendly" and will also give you a good start I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your problem correctly. Let me express what I think about.

I supposed that you want to the `g_list` be changed after you get input from stdin, and save the changes of `g_list` in its original file.

What the g_list.py looks like this:

```py
# g_list.py
guilds = ['a', 'b']
```

And another file called g_add.py which provide the add action:

```
# g_add.py
import pickle

from g_list import guilds


def g_add():
    # I think you want the `Guilds_Sorted.txt` be a temp file
    # and each time you run this script recreate that file.
    # use a `with` statement to do this so you don't need to
    # open and close the file manuallyy
    # the interpreter will do those jobs for you
    with open('Guilds_Sorted.txt', 'w'):
        pass  # since you just want to create a file, do nothing

    try:
        while True:
            guild = input("What is the guild's name ? ")
            with open('Guilds_Sorted.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(guild + '\n')
                guilds.append(guild)

            # if you want to change the original guilds in g_list.py
            # you may have to rewrite the g_list.py like this

            guilds.sort()  # sort it before you save
            with open('g_list.py', 'w') as f:
                f.write('guilds = [')
                for guild in guilds:
                    f.write("'" + guild + '",')
                f.write("]")

            # actually this is not so graceful...
            # if you really want to save the data in a list
            # you can refer to the `pickle` standard library
            # it looks like this
            # with open("g_list.pkl", "wb") as f:
            #     pickle.dump(guilds, f)

            # and when you want to use guilds
            # with open("g_list.pkl", "rb") as f:
            #     guilds = pickle.load(f)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # you can exit by press `ctrl + c`
        print("exit...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g_add()
```

Comment: Thank you this would also work but wovano's code makes more sense than what i initialy attempted to do

Comment: @Xu_shan_shan, As you already indicated, just writing the guilds to a Python file this way is not really safe. It will break if the guild contains a single-quote. Using `pickle` indeed solves that problem, but as long as the guilds are all single-line strings, just using a text file is much easier then.

Comment: @wovano, Yep, your code is clean and nice! That is how a clear answer should be. I've learned a lot from you. And I also will try harder to be a better helper lol :)